jQuery Drag and Drop and update input
I need to have a drag and drop combined with click to browse. Click to browse works fine and drops the file into the input.
Drag and drop, on the other hand, works to the point of getting the file details from dataTransfer and even updating the drop zone with the file name - but, how can I then get that file into the input?
$('#ModalDropZone').on('drop', function () {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();

  const vInput = $('#DocFileUpload')
  alert("DropZone changed")
  var vFile = event.dataTransfer.files;
  var vName = event.dataTransfer.files[0].name;
  var vLength = vFile.length;

  if (vLength > 0) {
    alert(vName);
    // vInput.files = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    vInput.files = event.dataTransfer.files;
    $('#ModalDropZone').html(vName);
    $('#DocFileUpload').files(vFile);
  }
});

UPDATE
Having tried about every possible combination of adding this file to the input it either fails silently or blows out with an error.
In the debugger it's showing the file, but it's always a 'ghost' - if I try to get a handle on it afterwards (to upload) the length is aways zero.


Here an efficient way to upload file using drag&drop . You need to add these features to your code: an onchange on your file-upoad-INPUT + an Ajax-upload function to send the dropped file to your server via a server-side script: upload.php for example):
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Drag and Drop file upload using jQuery + AJAX</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
        <div class="upload-content">
            <span class="upload-content-title">Drop the file here or click to select it</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

script.js:
$('.upload-content').on('dragenter', function (e) {

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".upload-content-title").text("Release here");

});


$('.upload-content').on('dragover', function (e) {

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".upload-content-title").text("Release here");

});


$('.upload-content').on('drop', function (e) {

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".upload-content-title").text("Loading...");

    var fd = new FormData();

    var file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;

    fd.append('file', file[0]);

    upload(fd);

});

// Open file selector when click on div
$("#uploadfile").on('click', function () {
    $("#file").click();
});


$("#file").change(function () {

    var fd = new FormData();

    var files = $('#file')[0].files[0];

    fd.append('file', files);

    upload(fd);

});

function upload(formData) {

    $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: response => {

            console.log(response);

            $(".upload-content-title").text("Drop the file here or click to select it");

        }
    });

}

Source: https://github.com/DevCia/Drag-drop-file-upload-jquery-ajax
